# For some reason my PHP code isn't working

Tags: php, html, loops, if-statement

So my code is supposed to print out all of the users of my game in ASC (ascending) order by ID. It does this fine, but for some reason it won't print their names correctly...

Here is my code:

```
<table width="90%" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;border:4px solid #9f0606;">
  <tr height="41">
    <td align="center" colspan="2" style="border-collapse:collapse;border:4px solid #9f0606;"><strong>User List</strong></td>
  </tr>
<?
$presult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC") or die(mysql_error());
$b = 0;                    
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($presult)) {
?>
  <tr height="31">
    <td width="80%" style="border-collapse:collapse;border:4px solid #9f0606;" align="left">
      <?php
$b = $b + 1;
if($row['account_type'] == 1){
echo "<p><a style=\"color:black;text-decoration:none;\" href=\"view_profile.php?id=". $row['id'] ."\">".$row['username']."&nbsp;[".$row['id']."]</a></p>";
?>
     </td>
   <td width="20%" style="border-collapse:collapse;border:4px solid #9f0606;" align="left">
<?
echo "<p>Level:&nbsp;".$row['level']."</p>";
?>
  </td>
</tr>
<?
}elseif($row['account_type'] == 2){
?>
echo "<p><a style=\"color:#CC0000;text-decoration:none;\" href=\"view_profile.php?id=". $row['id'] ."\">".$row['username']."&nbsp;[".$row['id']."]</a></p>";
?>
  </td>
 <td width="20%" style="border-collapse:collapse;border:4px solid #9f0606;" align="left">
<?
echo "<p>Level:&nbsp;".$row['level']."</p>";
?>
</td>
 </tr>
<?
}else{
?>
echo "<p><a style=\"color:black;text-decoration:none;\" href=\"view_profile.php?id=". $row['id'] ."\">".$row['username']."&nbsp;[".$row['id']."]</a></p>";
?>
 </td>
<td width="20%" style="border-collapse:collapse;border:4px solid #9f0606;" align="left">
<?
echo "<p>Level:&nbsp;".$row['level']."</p>";
    ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?
}
}
?>
</table>
```

Sorry that it's not very clean or organized, having to space everything 4 times gets annoying so I let it look a bit sloppy.

Here's a screenshot of what the code looks like for me in-browser:

(I cant post images because I don't have 10 reputation yet apparently, but basically the screenshot shows the username/id part looking like this:

```
echo "

`this row in blue`".$row['username']." [".$row['id']."]

";?>
```

and the level part looking exactly how I want it, like this:

```
Level: 12)
```

As you can see, the "level" part of the loop (printing the user's level) works fine. If you can find the error in the rest of my code, that would be awesome. Oh and by the way, where it says ($row['account_type'] == 1), none of the users are account_type == 1, the first one is account_type == 6, and the second one is account_type == 2. They all print exactly the same. Thanks!

Image here:

[image]

Comment: Did you read the section in the help docs about appropriate titles?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Can you post the images now.

Comment: Do you know where I can find that?

Comment: Given you seem to be getting raw PHP code in your browser, you've got a major coding flaw somewhere. badly placed/missing `<?php` and `?>` tags most likely.

Comment: He means be specific in your title. You current title could apply to thousands of other questions, literally.

Comment: Yes I will post the image @woz

Comment: You should learn how to use a proper text editor that can do things for you like indenting a block of code 4 spaces. That way, formatting code for StackOverflow will not be a pain.

Comment: When you post code, use `<pre>` instead of 4 spaces

Comment: is that the way of putting html through php they're teaching at school? I just can't understand why people keep opening and closing php three hundred times in a script instead of putting html code in variables from templates, achieving a nice visually arranged code and a single `echo $html` at end of script. It is also noteworthy that echoing two hundred times in a script will be longer then echoing the same html code in a single time.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: Unfortunately, that's the way PHP was originally designed to be used, so it's no surprise that people use it that way.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Do you use an IDE? Code such as `class=\"blah\"` or `don\'t` looks horrible and IDE's don't color them correctly.

Comment: @rybo111 Yep, I use IDE's, but I organize my code in such a way that html code goes in html files, and php code goes in php files, so that I don't have to escape everything and colors fit the code. Also be sure to absolutely master single against double quotes, because you should not really have to escape quotes that often, except maybe when writing javascript lines in onchange events of html elements directly in a variable in php.

Comment: @rybo11 for exemple, if you write html in php, it goes in single quotes, so you don't have to escape the double quotes. You need to concatenate a value from php through it? close a single quote, put your value and open the single quote. I don't know why you would carve the word `don't` in your code, it sould come from a database.. in which case you don't really need to escape the quotes before echoing, they will nicely stay there in a php variable.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I understand the concept of using single quotes inside double quotes and vice versa. I'm not sure how you use HTML in PHP without using a PHP file.

Comment: @rybo111 with the powerful strtr() function. I set templates in html, with placeholders such as `{zID}`, separating sections (like body and header) with special characters such as `~`. in php, with `$aTemplate = explode('~'file_get_contents('path/html.html'))` I get a nice array, containing the html. then, `$html = strtr($aTemplate[1],array('{zID}' => 26153))` will put your html code, with placeholders replaced, in `$html`, which you can echo. I hope it's of any conceivable use :)

Comment: @rybo111: You're probably better off using a proper template library like Mustache ( https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php ), or Laravel's Blade. If you create your own template system (I've done this before) then you end up wanting to add more and more features. In the end you will either screw up your templating system by filling it with bad features, or (if you do it well) just duplicating work that other people have already done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are closing the php `?>` too soon in multiple places:

```
<table width="90%" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;border:4px solid #9f0606;">
  <tr height="41">
    <td align="center" colspan="2" style="border-collapse:collapse;border:4px solid #9f0606;"><strong>User List</strong></td>
  </tr>
<?
$presult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC") or die(mysql_error());
$b = 0;                    
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($presult)) {
?>
  <tr height="31">
    <td width="80%" style="border-collapse:collapse;border:4px solid #9f0606;" align="left">
      <?php
$b = $b + 1;
if($row['account_type'] == 1){
echo "<p><a style=\"color:black;text-decoration:none;\" href=\"view_profile.php?id=". $row['id'] ."\">".$row['username']."&nbsp;[".$row['id']."]</a></p>";
?>
     </td>
   <td width="20%" style="border-collapse:collapse;border:4px solid #9f0606;" align="left">
<?
echo "<p>Level:&nbsp;".$row['level']."</p>";
?>
  </td>
</tr>
<?
}elseif($row['account_type'] == 2){
?>
```

***** HERE FOR EXAMPLE *****************

```
echo "<p><a style=\"color:#CC0000;text-decoration:none;\" href=\"view_profile.php?id=". $row['id'] ."\">".$row['username']."&nbsp;[".$row['id']."]</a></p>";
?>
  </td>
 <td width="20%" style="border-collapse:collapse;border:4px solid #9f0606;" align="left">
<?
echo "<p>Level:&nbsp;".$row['level']."</p>";
?>
</td>
 </tr>
<?
}else{
?>
```

********** AND HERE *****************

```
echo "<p><a style=\"color:black;text-decoration:none;\" href=\"view_profile.php?id=". $row['id'] ."\">".$row['username']."&nbsp;[".$row['id']."]</a></p>";
?>
 </td>
<td width="20%" style="border-collapse:collapse;border:4px solid #9f0606;" align="left">
<?
echo "<p>Level:&nbsp;".$row['level']."</p>";
    ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?
}
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't see what you mean D:... Could you show me a fix?

Comment: after that elseif(.....){ you are closing php tag (you gave ?> ) this will end php code, but then you are still typing php code (echo "...."

Comment: thats just one place, have a t least one more mistake like that, I suggest you use a good editor with colors and indent your code

Comment: Ohmygod duh... Thanks you guys

Comment: I've been staring at that code for like 15 minutes and I finally decided to post it here

Comment: You should split your source code into different parts.
It's not recommended to directly add queries in a view.
Take a look to Model-View-Controller pattern or you can create functions in a separated PHP file containing queries. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller